# CSS performance- descendant selector vs. class selector

Tags: css, performance

I appending table dynamically using javascript in html with say 50000 cells.

```
<table id="dataTable">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>data1</td>
           <td>data2</td>
           .....
           <td>data1</td>
       </tr>
       ..........
       <tr>
           <td>data1</td>
           <td>data2</td>
           .....
           <td>data1</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm styling the td with descendant selector as,

```
#dataTable td{
     text-align:right;
     border:1px solid #adadad;
     padding-right:10px;
}
```

Another option is to give class to each td using class selector.

```
<table id="dataTable">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td class="format">data1</td>
           <td class="format">data2</td>
           .....
           <td class="format">data1</td>
       </tr>
       ..........
       <tr>
           <td class="format">data1</td>
           <td class="format">data2</td>
           .....
           <td class="format">data1</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here we have used format class for styling.

```
.format{
     text-align:right;
     border:1px solid #adadad;
     padding-right:10px;
}
```

I'm facing performance issue while rendering the table in browser. Is this because I've used DESCENDANT SELECTOR INSTEAD OF CLASS SELECTOR.
Or Browser is not able handle large data.

Answer (score 1):

**About the table performance**

Tables can be slow to render mostly due to the dynamic column sizes that need to be calculated and set on every change.

You can solve this by specifying a fixed size for each column, like so:

```
#dataTable td {
    width: 100px; /* Set sizes appropriately */
}
```

This should make your table more performant

**About CSS performance**

CSS selects by the last token first, so for example, to execute the following selector:

```
#dataTable td
```

CSS will first select ALL `td` elements and then check if each of them is a descendant of `#dataTable`. Technically, specifying a class for each cell is faster.

However, this is probably not significant enough to pay for by complicating your overall design.

I recommend reading [Efficiently Rendering CSS](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) by CSS-Tricks to get a better idea about CSS and performance.

Comment: Thanks for the Effeciently Rendering CSS link.Won't it cause any performance issue to render class="format" 50000 times. And if this is not goind to cuase any problem then what is the significance of using Descendant selectors.

Comment: I believe (since I didn't read the actual implementation) that what matters is the size of the groups of elements that are being selected in your selector. `td` will select a group of the same size as `.format` given every table cell has that class name. Performance gains from adjustment to class names in your case will be insignificant, but probably won't do any harm either.

Comment: I'm clear how descendant selector works but what is the significance of using Descendant selector? If we can use class selector.              And my concern was to add class="format" 50000 times on html. And I'm not talking of reducing manual efforts of adding it I'm using foreach loop to print it.

Comment: Adding `class="format"` 50000 times shouldn't be a problem, as for the significance between the two selectors, it seem to be about the same given almost (if not all) elements captured by `td` are a match.

Comment: I'm still not clear. If Descendant selectors are inefficient because, for each element that matches the key, the browser must traverse up the DOM tree, evaluating every ancestor element until it finds a match or reaches the root element. The less specific the key, the greater the number of nodes that need to be evaluated. **Why there is need to use Descendant Selectors?** There must be some special scenarios where they are advantageous.